# Cosmological constant

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, cosmological-constant

I have always wondered about how [cosmological constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant) is characterized. So since it is still a hypothesis you often read the “cosmological constant measured to be ….”. Shouldn't the statement read “cosmological constant calculated to be ….” . Or Is it that such semantics does not matter.

Comment: If we could calculate the cosmological constant, we'd have a much better idea what it's value is. ;)

Comment: yes, both words are bad, but "measurement" sound worse. Maybe something like "hypothetically calculated".

Comment: Sorry, @QSA, this happens quite often and I would like to know why it happens. Could you please explain to us why you think that the word "measure" means something else than "measure" in this context? When people say that they measure the cosmological constant, why do you decide that the word "measure" should mean  a totally, totally different verb "calculate"? I am just not getting it. Your modification seems not only obviously wrong but malicious to me, especially because you even seem to accuse the normal folks of inaccuracy - while it's clearly you who is bringing all the noise.

Comment: ... No one can calculate the right cosmological constant for our Universe today - if he could, we would probably have a complete TOE.

Comment: @QSA In fact, cosmological constant comes as a constant in an alternative solution for Einstein's field Equations. Now, we would have had no proof that it exists if it had not been measured.

Comment: @lubos, my reason for this question is to clarify the concept for myself, I have no other motives. Of course many measurements are done indirectly, but this case is a bit unusual, it goes too far. We are not measuring vacuum energy density directly (or indirectly) because we cannot measure such a low number and hence we are not even sure it is not zero. The theory that modifies GR to include CC itself is a bit ad-hoc, but never mind that (although other theories have been proposed, even some claim data contradict CC).

Comment: The way then is to extract data from (CMB for example) by constructing various models to match data with formulas. Then we extract the value of CC for different models, this does not look like “measurement” in the usual sense. Typically we come up with theories via experimental results or use theory to explain experimental results. The models in this case are made based on the hypothesis that DE exists, and then DM was added to explain other observations, this I haven’t seen elsewhere.

Comment: But I am not against all that; we do what we have to, this is  cosmology after all. I just thought either I am looking at it the wrong way, or a better characterization should be put forward to avoid confusion for the beginners.

Comment: @Cheeku, GR was modified to fit the observation of accelerated expansion.

Comment: @QSA GR was not *modified* to include the CC.  It was always there: the question was just is its value zero, or not.  Unfortunately, Einstein (at one point) gave it an arbitrary value for bad reasons, but that doesn't mean it shouldn't exist.

Comment: @QSA, i've amended my solution below to address your comment that ***The way then is to extract data from (CMB for example) by constructing various models to match data with formulas. Then we extract the value of CC for different models, this does not look like “measurement” in the usual sense.*** --- which is blatantly false.  That is exactly how *all* of science works.

Comment: @QSA the models are definitely based on the *premise* of having Dark Energy/Cosmological constant -- because those theories are the ones which best explain the data.  In fact, there are *no* other theories which even make a good attempt at fitting the data.  That doesn't mean that our current (minimal) understanding is correct---only that its the best direction to go to learn more.  That's always the goal

Comment: @QSA "I have always wondered about how the electron mass is characterized. So since it is still a hypothesis you often read the “the electron mass is measured to be ….”. Shouldn't the statement read “the electron mass is calculated to be ….” . Or Is it that such semantics does not matter." No difference from your question. After all, we didn't really know where the electron mass came from until last July, although they didn't exactly "measure" the Higgs either. It was inferred through a lot of other measurements and calculations. All of science is done through models.

Answer (score 4):

The cosmological constant can be measured just like any quantity.  In fact, the [2011 nobel prize in physics](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2011/press.html) was given for just that.

One of the earlier papers seriously analyzing the issue is [linked here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/bib_query?arXiv%3aastro-ph/9605017).  A more general overview can be found [here, on scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Cosmological_constant#Observational_evidence); and a [even more general one, targeted at a wider audience from Sean Carroll](http://preposterousuniverse.com/writings/encyc/).  You can also look at [this article on measurements with type Ia supernovae](http://hal.in2p3.fr/docs/00/01/47/49/PDF/democrite-00011141.pdf), specifically.

---

Edit:  On the nature of scientific measurement.

In astrophysics, measurements are very rarely done with rulers.  Instead, in the majority of cases, they are done by making comparisons between observations (done *with* rulers---in this case CCDs, etc) and the predictions of models.  This is the fundamental nature of scientific inference and deduction.

For example, consider the 'measurement' of mass (any mass):
There is no way to *directly measure* mass, it can only be inferred using one of many physical laws.  For example, by *measuring* the force of gravity, and using $F = G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r}$.  Alternatively, one could use a spring of a known strength, *measure* the frequency of oscillation and use $\omega^2 = \frac{k}{m}$.  Both methods use inference.

As the desired parameter becomes more complex---for example, a dynamic property of the universe (you know, no big deal)---the inferences become more complex.  The state of the art technique for inferring model-dependent parameters based on observational measurements is called [Bayesian Inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) - which can be used to take into account uncertainty on the models themselves, and make comparisons between models.  In general, scientists use Bayesian Inference implicitly when comparing between different competing models.  One must take into account confidence in a model, in addition to the observational data, to figure out not only what the 'measured values' of parameters are --- but also which models are the most compatible with the data.  This is how competing models are compared.

In the end, there can never be 100% certainty in either a 'measurement' (of a parameter) or a model in-and-of-itself.  Instead a scientist can only become more and more confident in a range of parameters, or a sufficient accuracy of a model.

Comment: Please see my reply to lubos, and your own references are full of statements that support what I am saying. For example the list of problems in your second ref, this is not exhaustive. "Despite its success, the cosmological constant is not without problems (for further details on all the issues below see Weinberg (1989), Carroll (2001), and Padmanabhan (2003))."

Comment: I would say that it isn't really "measured", as in the way you measure your weight on a bathroom scale.  A FRLW model is assumed for the universe, and an acceleration parameter is measured, and this predicts a cosmological constant.  But there are several assumptions that went into this, and if you model the cosmology a different way, you get different results.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer, yes in my answer is a rant on how most scientific measurement does differ from using a bathroom scale (excuse me, I used the term 'ruler').  It is none-the-less measurement.

Comment: @zhermes: sure.  But it is not 100% definitive that we live in a FRLW universe just yet.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer, first---I do appreciate your points, and I don't think we actually disagree on much (if anything), but again, as I said in my ramble, you can never be 100% sure of any measurement or model.

Comment: @zhermes: fine.  But you can be much more sure of certain things than others.  Anyway, we're getting hung up about connotations of words.  I"m out.

Comment: @zhermes, I have already said that we make a lot of measurements indirectly, but this case is a bit different as summarized by Jerry Schirmer. Also, I said the technique is necessary for the case at hand. But I guess the wording is a bit confusing but not necessarily wrong because any other description might be cumbersome.

Comment: @zhermes, Einstein added the CC on the LHS of the equation AFTER finding out that his model leads to an expanding universe and he wanted it to be static. Then it was set to zero after Hubble’s discovery. Only later it was moved to RHS and given the modern interpretation. I thought this was common knowledge, but of course it is not essential.

Comment: @QSA that's simply not the case.  It was obvious in the derivation of the field equations that there was freedom up to a scalar---the cosmological constant.  I believe it's in the 'Zurich Notebooks' if you'd like to look into it.  In any case, this thread has become useless.

Comment: @zhermes, thank you for the participation, all the posts have been useful to me.

Comment: @QSA I hope I've been able to help.